# Why are these inline-block elements outside their container?

Tags: css

As illustrated here:

http://jsbin.com/vavuvo/2

**HTML**

```
<div class="color-bar">
  <span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
```

**LESS**

```
.color-bar {
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;

  > span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 25%;
  }

  > span:nth-child(1) {
    background: blue;
  }
  > span:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
  }
  > span:nth-child(3) {
    background: purple;
  }
  > span:nth-child(4) {
    background: orange;
  }
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize editing it would change it realtime. I put it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for `vertical-align` is `baseline`. just set it to `top` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/06z63n7L/

```
.color-bar > span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 25%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```